# Displaying a table in a HTML page using Spring boot

Tags: java, html, spring-boot

I have a table that I want to fill with data from database using this spring boot controller,
I can fill my table with: the name of the user, the email, some actions ...
but I can't display the row of the id (the id is the the primary key).

It's giving me as an error:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error,
> status=500). An error happened during template parsing (template:
> "class path resource [templates/test.html]")

This is my entity:

```
package com.example.demo;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;

@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {
    // pour indiquer la clé primaire 
    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id" )
    //L' @GeneratedValueannotation consiste à configurer le mode d'incrémentation de la colonne
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long  user_id ; 

   private String username;
   private String password ; 
   private boolean enabled ;
   private String email ;

   @Column(name = "test",columnDefinition="int")
   private Long test;

   @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   //pour connecter les tables
   @JoinTable(
            name = "users_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
            )
   private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();


public Set<Role> getRoles() {
    return roles;
}

public Long getTest() {
    return this.test;
}

public void setTest(Long test) {
    this.test = test;
}

public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
    this.roles = roles;
}
   
public String getUsername() {

    return username ;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return enabled;
}
public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
public Long getId() {
    return this.user_id;
}
public void setId(Long user_id) {
    this.user_id = user_id;
}
public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
} 
}
```

This is my html page:

```
<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org" >
<head>
 
    <title> Page d'accueil </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/webjars/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/webjars/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/webjars/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>

        
    <div class="container text-center">

    <h1 th:inline="text">Hello [[${#httpServletRequest.remoteUser}]]!</h1>

     <!--  Bouton pour logout -->
    <form th:action="@{/logout}" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Sign Out" class="btn btn-info"/>
    </form>
    
         <!--  Bouton pour l'ajout -->

    <form th:action="@{/NewUser}" >
            <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-secondary" />
    </form>

    </div>



    <!--  Tabelau des utilisateurs -->
    <div>
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>E-mail</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Enabled</th>
                    <th>TEST</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>

            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr th:each="user: ${users}">
                    <td th:text="${user.user_id}">ID</td>
                    <td th:text="${user.email}">E-mail</td>
                    <td th:text="${user.username}">Name</td>
                    <td th:text="${user.enabled}">Enabled </td>
                    <td th:text="${user.test}">TEST </td>
                    
                    <td >
                        <form th:action="@{'/delete/'+${user.username}}" th:object="${user}" th:method="delete" >
                        <input   type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="delete">
                        </form>

                        <form th:action="@{'/EditUser/'+${user.username}}" th:object="${user}"  >
                        <input   type="submit"  class="btn btn-success" value="edit">
                        </form>

                       
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Java uses CamelCase as a practice for writing names of methods, variables, classes, packages and constants. so it's better to name your id as userId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should change the getter getUserId name to getUser_id and the setter setUserId to setUser_id.

the framework uses getters and setters to access the bean properties so when you write ${user.user_id} user.getuser_id() will be executed and in your case getuser_id() does not exist. and that's why for other fields it works fine and the problem occurs only with the id.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because thymeleaf internally uses geter and setter.
Try replacing these method:

```java
private Long  user_id;// wrong naming convention 
public Long getId() {
    return this.user_id;
}
public void setId(Long user_id) {
    this.user_id = user_id;
}
```

By this:

```java
private Long  userId;//use this
public Long getUserId() {
    return this.user_id;
}
public void setUserId(Long user_id) {
    this.user_id = user_id;
}
```

Or you can simply try this in thymeleaf(don't change anything in java):

```
<td th:text="${user.id}">ID</td>
```